# Back button handling Android

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, fragment

I am pretty new in android development and Kotlin. I created a navigation bar which is implemented this way in Kotlin programming language:

```
flScreen = findViewById(R.id.flScreen)
bnvNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bnvNavigation)
trainersFragment = TrainersFragment()
instrumentsFragment = InstrumentsFragment()

placeFragment(trainersFragment, false)

bnvNavigation.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.trainers -> {
            placeFragment(trainersFragment, true)
            true
        }
        R.id.instruments -> {
            placeFragment(instrumentsFragment, true)
            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}

private fun placeFragment(fragment: Fragment, addToStack: Boolean) {
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
        replace(R.id.flScreen, fragment)
        if (addToStack) addToBackStack("New fragment")
        commit()
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount == 0) {
        finish()
    }

    when (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flScreen)) {
        is TrainersFragment -> {
            super.onBackPressed()
            bnvNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.instruments
        }
        is InstrumentsFragment -> {
            super.onBackPressed()
            bnvNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.trainers
        }
        else -> super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is when user presses the back button on the application start, the activity does not get immediately finished, but instead passes to the switch case in onBackPressed function. How can I check if back stack is empty or not?

I tried to set different values of the if condition check, also I tried to restructure the switch case which didn't get useful.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can modify your onBackPressed function like this:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        // If there are fragments in the back stack, pop the back stack
        super.onBackPressed()
    } else {
        // If the back stack is empty, finish the activity
        finish()
    }

    // Now, you can handle switching between fragments based on the selected item
    when (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.flScreen)) {
        is TrainersFragment -> bnvNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.instruments
        is InstrumentsFragment -> bnvNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.trainers
        // Handle other fragments as needed
    }
}
```

With this modification, when the back button is pressed, it will check if the back stack has fragments. If it does, it will pop the back stack. If the back stack is empty, it will finish the activity.